# How can I convert WritableBitmap to BitmapImage

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, zxing

I am trying to use zxing Barcode library in a Windows Store app to produce barcode images.
No image is displayed.
What is wrong with the following?

View model:

```
      public BarcodeViewModel(INavigationService navigationservice, IDataService dataservice) : base(navigationservice, dataservice)
            {
                var bh = new BarcodeHelper();
                BarcodeImage = new Image() {Source = bh.GetBarcode("123123")};
            }

public Image BarcodeImage { get { return barcodeimage; } set { barcodeimage = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => BarcodeImage); } }
```

View:

```
<Image Source="{Binding BarcodeImage}"/>
```

Barcode class:

```
 public WriteableBitmap GetBarcode(string barcodetext)
        {
            IBarcodeWriter writer = new BarcodeWriter { Format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_128 };
            var result = writer.Write(barcodetext);
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your binding is wrong. `<Image />` should be bound with property type of `BitmapImage` rather than `Image` or do like this

```
<Image Source="{Binding BarcodeImage.Source}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it out myself. In the view, the source binding should read:

```
<Image Source="{Binding BarcodeImage.Source}"/>
```